# Magento muliple product having same name

Tags: magento-1.9

I have muliple product having same name so their url are  also generated  same.It is also creating problem regarding SEO duplication. 
How i fix it?

Comment: What do you want to fix ? url would not be completely same there would have been a suffix to the url

Comment: actually my doubt is it any problem in seo duplication

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, have products with the exact same name defeats the purpose of having unique products for SEO. In addition, to get the best SEO results you will want to match your URL, Title and content.

You should export all your products and open them in a spreadsheet. You can group by your product name in Excel (Or whatever program you use). Once you have grouped your names you can find the common name and concatenate your titles with another attribute from the product. This will give you unique names for each product.

If this is an ultimate naming convention that proves to work you can do it to all your products, but I would start with only the products that are matching to test your case. You will then want to truncate your existing core_url_rewrite table and re-import your products. You can then index and you will have unique names.

MAKE A BACKUP BEFORE YOU DO ANY DATABASE MODIFICATIONS!

Comment: Thanks for Responding after long search i found the solution. In Magento if have same product name have same url it automatically add product id

Comment: @LearningMagento That doesn't solve your SEO problem. You product name should match your url

Comment: Ok thanks for your information i will try this

Answer (score 0):

It may cause duplicate content penalties in worst case , you rename them by adding brand name , model number or key features to make them different. It would be better for users as well , as same name product can cause frustration and confusion between the users

Comment: actually we added more product it's very difficult to identify

Comment: Identify what ?

Comment: we have more then 6000+ product

Comment: Ok you can get same name by running a group by query and load product by id then append any unique attribute to their name and save the product

Comment: Thanks for Responding after long search i found the solution. In Magento if have same product name have same url it automatically add product id